# Thead is not repeating on page headers while printing

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I am using the following HTML structure and while taking print preview the THEAD contents is not repeating on every page. It is limited to the first page only

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
    thead { display:table-header-group }
    tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead style="background:red;">
            <tr style="height: 450px;"><th>heading</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr> <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
         <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr> <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr> <tr >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
       <tr  >
            <td style="padding:20px 20px;">x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

The reason for that seems like the fixed height of tr inside thead

```
    <thead style="background:red;">
        <tr style="height: 450px;"><th>heading</th></tr>
    </thead>
```

If we provide a less value like 200px this will work as expected. So any known limitations are there with keeping bigger thead contents as page header? In my case I have to support some logo and text under the logo and chances that the height then will be around a minimum of 350px - 400px  So any known ways to  overcome issues like this while keeping HTML pages ready to print

Comment: Have you tried [CSS printing units](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html#:~:text=CSS%20inherited%20the%20units%20pt,only%20use%20em%20and%20px%20.) (em, cm, mm, in, pt, pc, %) instead of pixels?

Comment: Not making any difference Issue is like if thead content is bigger it seems like page header is not appearing on pages